# Add Item to database/datagrid based on selection in other datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I have a WPF application in which I have to two datagrids. The first one shows Albums and the second one corresponding Songs, based on the selection in the first datagrid. I can also add an Album, which is then saved to the database. Now I want to select an album in the first datagrid and add a song to that album in the second datagrid. All songs have an AlbumID as a foreign key in my database. I don't know how to handle this parameter AlbumID when adding a Song to the database, my query crashes as expected.
I would like to know how I can tell the SongViewModel to add the Song with the AlbumID given by the SelectedAlbum.

Query to add Album:

```
   public AlbumData AddAlbumEntry(AlbumData albumData)
    {
        album albumEntry = new album
        {
            AlbumName = albumData.AlbumName,
            Year = albumData.AlbumYear,
        };

        _context.albums.Add(albumEntry);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return new AlbumData 
        {
            AlbumID = albumEntry.AlbumID,
            AlbumYear = albumEntry.Year,
            AlbumName = albumEntry.AlbumName,
        };
    }
```

Query to add song:

```
    public SongData AddSongEntry(SongData songData)
    {
        song songEntry = new song
        {
            SongName = songData.SongName,
            SongNumber = songData.SongNumber,

        };

        _context.songs.Add(songEntry);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return new SongData
        {
            SongID = songEntry.SongID,
            SongNumber = songEntry.SongNumber,
            SongName = songEntry.SongName,
        };
    }
```

AlbumViewModel to connect to View:

```
    public AlbumData AddAlbumEntry(AlbumData albumData)
    {
        var controller = new BandManagerController();
        return controller.AddAlbumEntry(albumData);
    }

    public void AlbumToDatabase(AlbumData data)
    {
        AddAlbumEntry(data);
        ExecuteCancelCommand();
    }
```

SongViewModel to connect to view:

```
    public SongData AddSongEntry(SongData songData)
    {
        var controller = new BandManagerController();
        return controller.AddSongEntry(songData);
    }

    public void SongToDatabase(SongData data)
    {
        AddSongEntry(data);
        ExecuteCancelCommand();
    }
```

I also have a SelectedAlbum property to fill the SongLists:

```
    public AlbumViewModel SelectedAlbum
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedAlbum;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_selectedAlbum != value)
            {
                _selectedAlbum = value;
            }

            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedAlbum");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. In the AlbumListViewModel I open the dialog where I can add Songs. I bound the AlbumId from the SongModel to the AlbumID from my AlbumModel via Selected Album. Now I can select an album and add a song with the corresponding AlbumID. The method for the command to add a song with the "add" button looks like:

```
    private void AddSong()
    {
        addSong.ShowDialog(new SongViewModel(new SongData { AlbumID = SelectedAlbum.AlbumID }));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try by creating View model that is easy to bind to ui. View model should have SelectedAlbum and SelectedSong properties so when you create new song you will already have information in view model about selected album, then you can set album id on song model.

```
class ViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private IDatabase _database;
    private Album _album;
    private Song _song;
    public ObservableCollection<Album> Albums { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Song> AlbumSongs { get; private set; }

    public ICommand AddAlbumCommand {get; private set;}
    public ICommand AddSongCommand {get; private set;}

    public Album SelectedAlbum
    {
        get => _album;
        set { LoadAlbumSongs(album); SetProperty(ref _album, value); }
    }

    public Song SelectedSong
    {
        get => _song;
        set => SetProperty(ref _song, value);
    }

    public ViewModel(IDatabase database)
    {
        _database = database;
        Albums = new ObservableCollection<Album>();
        AlbumSongs = new ObservableCollection<Song>();

        AddAlbumCommand = new RelayCommand (() => AddNewAlbum(),  () => true);
        AddSongCommand = new RelayCommand (() => AddNewSong(),  () => SelectedAlbum != null);
    }
    public void AddNewAlbum()
    {
        SelectedAlbum = new Album();
    }

    public void AddNewSong()
    {
        SelectedSong = new Song();
        SelectedSong.AlbumID = SelectedAlbum.AlbumID;
    }

    public void SaveAlbum()
    {
        if (SelectedAlbum.ID == 0) {
            Albums.Add(SelectedAlbum);
        }
        _database.SaveAlbum(SelectedAlbum);
    }

    public void SaveSong()
    {
        if (SelectedSong.ID == 0) {
            AlbumSongs.Add(SelectedSong);
        }
        _database.SaveSong(SelectedSong);
    }
}
```